# Java parallel queries and read/writing I/O

Tags: java, performance, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

A system is generating 10k values every 10Min and I need to use system output to lookup on a table to get the key to select from another table and dump the select output to file.

Looping on all values and fetching the data from DB is taking time 50Min which is not reasonable to process the backlog data generated by the system.

I need to do some kind of parallel processing to achieve this process in a reasonable time.

I am trying to use parallel stream but it seems variables inside lamda are not totally isolated and some deadlock if I have the right understanding.

If someone can guide me How can I achieve the target process:

[image: ER Diagram for the proccess]

What I have so far:

```
    // get all lines
    List<String> collections = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(child.toString()));
    //empty files check
    if (collections.size() != 0) {
      isDataEmptye[0] = true;
      writer[0] = CreateFile(child);
      APIMethod.logeInfo("Fetching Data From Source...");
    }
    //connection estab...
    Statement query;
    query = DBSQLQuery.getCon().createStatement();
    //start loop in paraller
    collections.parallelStream().forEach((collection) -> {
      String[] newQuery = null;
      try {

        countInputRecord[0]++;//for reporting 
        String[] value = {collection};
        if (value[0].length() <= invalid_record_length) {
          APIMethod.logeInfo("Invalid Record: " + value[0]);
          return;
        }
        // true in our case //Query on table A to get key by value
        if (RowIDMode) {
          String[] serialNum = {null};
          String[] rowIDQuery = {First_Lookup_Query.replace("$Key_value", ("'" + value + "'"))};
          if (dubgLevelFlag) {
            APIMethod.dubgLogInfo(" Trying To Lookup values with query : " + rowIDQuery[0]);
          }
          ResultSet[] resultSet = {query.executeQuery(rowIDQuery[0])};

          APIMethod.dubgLogInfo(" sizse : " + resultSet[0].getFetchSize());

          while (resultSet[0].next()) {
            serialNum[0] = resultSet[0].getString(1);
            if (dubgLevelFlag) {
              APIMethod.dubgLogInfo("The new Value is: " + serialNum[0]);
            }
            break;// only one record
          }
          resultSet[0].close();

          if (serialNum[0] == null) {
            if (dubgLevelFlag) {
              APIMethod.dubgLogInfo("Serial Number For Row ID : " + value[0] + " Not Found ");
            }
            LookupNotFound[0]++;
            return;
          } else {
            if (dubgLevelFlag) {
              APIMethod.dubgLogInfo(
                  "Serial Number For Row ID [" + value[0] + "] is [" + serialNum[0] + "]");
            }
            value = serialNum;
          }
        }
        // End of Query 1
        newQuery[0] = sql.replace("$ConditionFlage", whereKey + "=" + "'" + value[0] + "'");

        if (dubgLevelFlag) {
          APIMethod.dubgLogInfo("Run sql : " + newQuery[0]);
        }

        ResultSet sourceSet = query.executeQuery(newQuery[0]);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = sourceSet.getMetaData();
        int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
        boolean crmRetrieved = false;
        while (sourceSet.next()) {
          countCRMsubscriber[0]++;
          crmRetrieved = true;
          String columnValue = "";
          for (int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
            columnValue += sourceSet.getString(i);
          }
          if (dubgLevelFlag) {
            APIMethod.dubgLogInfo("Data Retrieved : " + columnValue);
          }
          writer[0].append(columnValue + "\n");
          writer[0].flush();
          if (count[0] % BachSize == 0 && count[0] != 0) {
            writer[0].close();
            APIMethod.logeInfo("Batch  size is completed,File : [" + name + "] Closed");
            tmpToTxtRename();
            APIMethod.logeInfo("Output File has been Created Successfully [" + name + "]");
            copy();
            writer[0] = CreateFile(child);
          }

          count[0]++;
          if (count[0] % 100 == 0) {
            writer[0].flush();
            APIMethod.logeInfo("   " + count[0] + "  Record(s) have been added and "
                + countInputRecord[0] + " Record(s) have been processed");
          }
          break;// only the first record is required
        }
        sourceSet.close();
        if (crmRetrieved == false) {
          if (dubgLevelFlag) {
            APIMethod.dubgLogInfo("No Data Retrieved From Source For Value : " + value);
          }
        }
        //end try
      } catch (SQLException sqlexc) {
        String mesg = "There is an error while querying  in Source Data <br /> <br />" + sql;
        APIMethod.logeErorCon(sqlexc, mesg);
        CRMRejectedRecords[0]++;
        APIMethod.logdubgErorCon(sqlexc, mesg);
        APIMethod.dubgLogInfo(APIMethod.getStackTrace(sqlexc));
        APIMethod.dubgLogInfo("run sql : " + newQuery);
        return;
      } catch (Exception ex) {
        APIMethod.logeEror(ex);
        DBSQLQuery.closConnection();

        System.exit(1);
      }
      // Select queries on collection
      // Update queries on collection

    });//end forEach()
```

Profiler output:

```
-Xprof output
Interpreted + native   Method
 93.9%     0  + 34425    java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0
  0.0%     6  +     3    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1
  0.0%     0  +     6    sun.nio.fs.UnixNativeDispatcher.readdir
  0.0%     6  +     0    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.<init>
  0.0%     3  +     0    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection
  0.0%     3  +     0    java.io.Writer.append
  0.0%     3  +     0    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8TTIdty.typeRep
  0.0%     3  +     0    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.marshal
  0.0%     3  +     0    org.apache.logging.log4j.core.pattern.MessagePatternConverter.format
  0.0%     0  +     2    java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0
  0.0%     0  +     2    java.io.UnixFileSystem.getBooleanAttributes0
  0.0%     2  +     0    com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.<init>
  0.0%     2  +     0    sun.reflect.UTF8.encode
  0.0%     2  +     0    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.readRPA
  0.0%     2  +     0    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.prepareAccessors
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.lang.Class.getPrimitiveClass
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.lang.Object.getClass
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.lang.Class.getConstantPool
  0.0%     1  +     0    java.lang.System.nanoTime
  0.0%     1  +     0    java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.io.FileInputStream.open0
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntryTime
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged
  0.0%     1  +     0    java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntryMethod
  0.0%     1  +     0    oracle.jdbc.driver.CancelLock$State.<init>
 94.2%    95  + 34449    Total interpreted (including elided)

     Compiled + native   Method
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.lang.Object.<init>
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.lang.StringBuilder.append
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.lang.String.valueOf
  0.0%     0  +     1    oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.<init>
  0.0%     0  +     1    oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.lessThan
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.io.DataOutputStream.writeInt
  0.0%     0  +     1    sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler.parseURL
  0.0%     1  +     0    oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.handleODBC
  0.0%     1  +     8    Total compiled

         Stub + native   Method
  5.6%     0  +  2039    java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0
  0.0%     0  +     9    java.io.FileOutputStream.writeBytes
  0.0%     7  +     1    java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1
  0.0%     0  +     6    java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntry
  0.0%     0  +     6    java.util.zip.Inflater.inflateBytes
  0.0%     0  +     4    java.lang.Object.hashCode
  0.0%     0  +     4    java.lang.ClassLoader.findBootstrapClass
  0.0%     0  +     3    java.lang.System.nanoTime
  0.0%     0  +     3    java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass0
  0.0%     0  +     2    java.lang.Object.clone
  0.0%     0  +     2    java.lang.System.identityHashCode
  0.0%     0  +     2    java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged
  0.0%     0  +     2    java.lang.System.arraycopy
  0.0%     0  +     2    java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0
  0.0%     1  +     1    java.lang.Class.forName0
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.lang.Class.getConstantPool
  0.0%     0  +     1    sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.lang.System.currentTimeMillis
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.util.zip.ZipFile.getEntryBytes
  0.0%     0  +     1    sun.reflect.ConstantPool.getUTF8At0
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.lang.Throwable.fillInStackTrace
  0.0%     0  +     1    java.lang.Thread.isInterrupted
  0.0%     0  +     1    sun.misc.Unsafe.compareAndSwapObject
  5.7%     8  +  2094    Total stub

  Thread-local ticks:
  0.0%     6             Class loader


Flat profile of 0.01 secs (1 total ticks): pool-1-thread-1

  Interpreted + native   Method
100.0%     0  +     1    java.io.FileOutputStream.close0
100.0%     0  +     1    Total interpreted


Flat profile of 0.02 secs (1 total ticks): DestroyJavaVM

  Thread-local ticks:
100.0%     1             Blocked (of total)


Global summary of 372.87 seconds:
100.0% 36663             Received ticks
  0.7%   256             Compilation
  0.0%     6             Class loader
```

Comment: Does the documentation of your JDBC driver say that it is safe to be used by multiple threads? Even when it is, using a single `Statement` object for all queries concurrently surely is not supported.

Comment: Besides that, you should rethink your habit of creating one-element arrays for no reason. When I go through all of your `[0]` occurrences, I find two categories. One where the array serves no purpose and can be replaced by a simple ordinary variable and the other, where you are performing updates without thread safety.

Comment: You should not be using same connection / statement across several threads, and you may find your processing time is quicker if you use single thread and `PreparedStatement` with bind variables instead of multiple edited SQL parsed+executed many times.

Comment: Try to move the following inside the foreach block:
Statement query;
query = DBSQLQuery.getCon().createStatement();

additionally, you may redesign to use a connection pool with multi-threading.